# What's the best way to add Tilemaps to QGIS without having to use Webmercator?

Tags: qgis

I'm looking for a good way to add tilemaps in qgis that are either in a custom projection or that I can reproject in qgis.  I have used the openlayers plugin to add basemap layers, but it forces me to use webmercator.  I have also spent some time playing with adding layers as a gdal wms as described here http://www.gdal.org/frmt_wms.html, but layers added in this manner are very slow even in their native projection.

My end goal would be to have ortho photos in a fast format in my local projection, and to be able to make some custom basemaps.

Comment: Speed may have something to do with the computer infrastructure between the screen and the data. Can you describe that?